# Difference between extension and static helper functions in Swift

Tags: swift

I am writing some helper functions for my Swift Project. I am not sure about 2 approaches and what's the pros/cons:

```
// use extension: 

extension SKAction {
  public static func blink(
    count: Int,
    outDuration: TimeInterval,
    inDuration: TimeInterval,
    chillDuration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction
  {
    var actions = [SKAction]()
    for i in 0..<count {
      let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: outDuration)
      let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: inDuration)
      actions += [fadeOut, fadeIn]
      if chillDuration > 0 {
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: chillDuration)
        actions += [wait]
      }
    }
    return SKAction.sequence(actions)
  }
}

// use static util
public final class SKAnimationUtil {

  public static func createBlinkAnimation(
    count: Int,
    outDuration: TimeInterval,
    inDuration: TimeInterval,
    chillDuration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction
  {
    var actions = [SKAction]()
    for i in 0..<count {
      let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: outDuration)
      let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: inDuration)
      actions += [fadeOut, fadeIn]
      if chillDuration > 0 {
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: chillDuration)
        actions += [wait]
      }
    }
    return SKAction.sequence(actions)
  }
}
```

The static util is what I normally do before. But then I found that SKAction already come with lots of factory functions (e.g. `SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration:)`).

Comment: If you are *never* creating an instance of the class `SKAnimationUtil` it would be better to use an enum, with your static methods on that, but if you can create an instance of it leave it as a class. With regards to whether it should be an extension or not, are you accessing `self` in the function call, if not then it doesn't need to be an extension?

Comment: @Andrew nope, i never create instance for that. But do you feel it's odd to make it an "Enum"? because in my mind, enum is to represent different cases.

Comment: You can use enum for name spacing.  You don't have to even create cases.  Check out these links: https://cocoacasts.com/namespaces-in-swift https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/powerful-ways-to-use-swift-enums/#namespaces-and-non-initializable-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, declaring a class whose name starts with SK is illegal. Two-letter capital letter prefixes on type names are reserved for Apple! I like to start everything with `My` to get around that rule.

OK, so on to the actual question: there is absolutely no significant difference between

```
extension SKAction {
    public static func blink(
```

and

```
public final class SKAnimationUtil {
    public static func createBlinkAnimation(
```

These are static methods, so they are effectively global, and the only reason for wrapping them in a type (SKAction or your utility class) is to *namespace* them in a nice way. (The static method is not *using* anything about its surrounding class.) The concept of "nice" is entirely subjective, so any further distinction would be a matter of opinion.

However, having said all that, I would just say that what I personally do is like the first example. What namespace "should" this method belong to? It is an SKAction factory, as you rightly say, so it can go nicely in SKAction. There is no reason to add to the existing stock of classes just to hold this method.

Consider, in particular, that the only reason for making a class is in order to *instantiate* that class. But you are *never* going to make an SKAnimationUtil *instance*, so Occam's Razor alone is enough to make one cry foul. This is not a helper in the classic sense.

Finally, I will just add that namespacing "holders" of static methods is best done, in Swift, using a struct or (even better nowadays) an enum. A class, even a final class, is *way* too much overhead for the job.

Comment: is it a convention nowadays to put static util functions to a "Enum"? or is it anti-pattern? in my mind, enum is to represent different cases. In other languages (like java), i always see classes being used to hold util functions

Comment: This is not another language. It is Swift. Java doesn't _have_ any types that are not classes. Swift does. "Each thing is just the thing that it is, and not some other thing." As for your question about the use of enums for this purpose, it is what Apple currently prefers, and I like to follow their lead. An enum, with no cases but with static methods, is the most lightweight namespacer.